# Send request to googleapis, response is empty

Tags: curl, google-api, google-drive-api

When I send a second request to [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com) with "curl", in linux based system, I will get empty response.

This is the first request :

```
[GET /drive/v2/files?maxResults=1&q=trashed%3dfalse%20and%20%271elDR9YhpT4IDDSur0SDGDWNa1w3pJKTX%27%20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%3d%27application%2fvnd%2egoogle%2dapps%2efolder%27%20and%20title%3d%272021%2d01%2d07%27&fields=items%28id%29 HTTP/1.0
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer ....
```

This is the response of the first request.

```
[{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "1fgsulr9gpOJFzY2kybYNI6roa0iZVfAa"
  }
 ]
}
]
```

This is the times request :

```
[GET /drive/v2/files?maxResults=1&q=trashed%3dfalse%20and%20%271fgsulr9gpOJFzY2kybYNI6roa0iZVfAa%27%20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%21%3d%27application%2fvnd%2egoogle%2dapps%2efolder%27%20and%20title%3d%27REC%5f2021%2d01%2d07%5f21%2d06%2d38%5fiCRa0cz3z%2emp4%27&fields=items%28id%2cfileSize%29 HTTP/1.0
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer .....
```

Same as the first times request

And I got the empty response from the second request. Even if I exchanged the order of sending the request. The second response of the second request will be empty. I tried to send a third fourth request with the same Authorization . The response is empty too. It can only works for the first request.

This situation has occurred since yesterday. Are there any changes about googleapi?

Comment: can you try changing fields=items%28id%29 to fields=* and see if that changes your result.

Comment: Why are you using drive v2?  why not use drive v3?